# how to upload images in netbeans7.0.1

Tags: netbeans-7

I have the doubt in uploading images in NetBeans7.0.1. 
There is no fileupload button in NetBeans7.0.1. Can we it into pallet or is there any another way to upload image?

Comment: Why should an IDE have a file-upload button?

Comment: i want to insert image into sql and i have to show it in the desktp application

Comment: That is not specific to NetBeans. You have to code it yourself. 

Read the byte content of the image, open a JDBC connection to the DB, invoke a SQL-INSERT query to insert the image into the DB, close the DB connection. 
Your "desktop" application has to do the reverse part: open a DB connection, invoke a SQL-Query to get the persisted byte-content, display the image

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer for my doubt that is, i just take a label and set a icon from reading the path from file dialog and converted image into byte and inserted into the sql with query that's it
the code:

```
  try{
            fd1=new FileDialog(this,"Open",FileDialog.LOAD);          // filedialog box        open
        fd1.show();
        fos1=new FileInputStream(fd1.getDirectory()+fd1.getFile());   //get the path from filedialog box
        String fileName=fd1.getDirectory()+fd1.getFile();   
         java.io.File f = new java.io.File (fileName);              //read the file
        int fileSize = (int) f.length();                     // read the file size
          bytes= new byte[fileSize];                    //convert into bytes
         FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f);
         fis.read(bytes);                              //read the bytes
        System.out.println("image inserted");
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(bytes);         // set bytes to icon
         photo.setIcon(icon);                          //set icon to label
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schoolmngt","root","root");
       PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("update studentpersonal set image=? where stadmno='"+admno.getText()+"'");  
       pst.setBytes(1,bytes);                           //insert bytes into sql db
         pst.execute();
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {ee.printStackTrace();}
```